# How to check in jQuery is a table cell overflow in width?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In other words, is there a way to get width of cell text in spite of overflowing?

Answer (score 2):

There's a concept of a 'text node', but frankly I don't know how to access its width. My first instinct is if it's a must-have, wrap the cell contents up in a span and get the span's width. Strikes me as kind of ugly, but sometimes purpose is more important than appearance. ;-)

```
$('td span').width(); // the width
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cvv4b/

If you really need to avoid the span, you could write a wee little utility that gets the text, copies it into a hidden element that doesn't have a width restriction (this element could be created on the fly if need be), and return the width of that hidden element.

Comment: It works, thanks. In Web every crossbrowser-working trick has good appearance :-)